# How to add GeoPoint to firebase collection in asp.net core

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, google-cloud-firestore

I can add string to the Firebase collection, but I need to add Longitude and Latitude to a field with geopoint datatype.

How do I pass the long and lat **12.146644,-68.277466** to save in the collection

```
 public async Task<string> CreateData(Data data)
        {
            try
            {
               
                CollectionReference collectionReference = _firestoreDb.Collection("Data");
                var response = await collectionReference.AddAsync(data);
                return response.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
          
        }
```

POCO

```
[FirestoreData]
    public class Data
    {
    
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string username{ get; set; } 
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string name { get; set; } 
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string loglat{ get; set; }**//this represents the concatenated value of long and lat** 
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string street { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I made the property loglat a type of GeoPoint

```
  [FirestoreData]
    public class Data
    {
    
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string username{ get; set; } 
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string name { get; set; } 
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public GeoPoint loglat{ get; set; }**//this represents the concatenated value of long and lat** 
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string street { get; set; }
       
    }
```

so

```
 public async Task<string> CreateData(DataDTO data2)
        {
            try
            {
                var lat = double.Parse(data2.latitude);
                var lon = double.Parse(data2.longtitude);

                GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);

                Data data = new Data
                {
                    username = data2.username,
                    name = data2.name,
                    loglat = geoPoint,
                    street = data2.street,

                };

                CollectionReference collectionReference = _firestoreDb.Collection("Data");
                var response = await collectionReference.AddAsync(data);
                return response.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
          
        }
```